# how to write 2 queries in the start method of batch class based on condition

Tags: apex, batch

how to write 2 queries in the start method of batch class based on the condition

```
select id,name,email from Account where createddate=today
select accountid,Account.name from Contact where account.closeddate=today and createdate=today
```

Comment: You can use use the inner query as Contact is a child of Account. `SELECT Name, Email, (select Id FROM Contacts WHERE Account.ClosedDate = today AND CreateDate = today) FROM Account WHERE CreatedDate = Today`, you can adjust the contact fields as per your need, and the contact fields you will get on the respected Account record, and all child records you will get which satisfy the condition.

Comment: Your queries don't literally work, because some fields don't exist. The answer to what you can do largely depend on what the precise queries are, so please consider editing your question to include the proper queries.

Comment: Much simpler to fire up two separate batches. Note that returning an iterator instead of a `QueryLocator` from the `start` method limits the number of rows that can be processed to 50,000 instead of 50 million - not likely to be a problem for your queries but often an important factor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to have one batch to work on both of those sets of data, you can add the query results to a `List<sObject>` and use that in your batch.

```
public class AccountContactBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>
{
    public List<sObject> start(Database.BatchableContext c)
    {
        List<sObject> scope = new List<sObject>();
        scope.addAll([select id,name,email from Account where createddate=today]);
        scope.addAll([select accountid,Account.name from Contact where
                      account.closeddate=today and createdate=today]);
        return scope;
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext c, List<sObject> scope)
    {
        for(sObject obj : scope)
        {
            switch on obj
            {
                when Account acc
                {
                    //Do account stuff
                }
                when Contact cont
                {
                    //Do contact stuff
                }
             }
         }
     }

     public void finish(Database.BatchableContext c)
     {
     }
}
```

Comment: You cannot add a contact to an account list (error is `System.TypeException: Collection store exception adding all List<Contact> to List<Account>`). Instead, you actually need to do this: `sobject[] scope = new sobject[0]; scope.addAll([select ... from account...]); scope.addAll([select ... from contact...]); return scope;`

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks, forgot the query result would be typed.